# python beautiful soup extract value from very complex div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm newbie on python & struggling to get to "lastPrice":"18,770.00" which is inside 'data' in the below div. Any help is greatly appreciated. I want to get 18770 as output

{"valid":"true","isinCode":null,"lastUpdateTime":"22-MAY-2015 15:30:06",instrument=-&symbolCount=2","tradedDate":"22MAY2015","data":[{"change":"-160.40","bestSell":"-37.04","annualisedVolatility":"30.24","lastPrice":"18,770.00","highPrice":"18,725.00"}],"eqLink":""}

Comment: can you please format your code so that it is readable?

Comment: I've added my code. Hope this is better

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you could just

```
data =json.loads(bs.findall("responseDiv").text())
data["data"]["lastPrice"]
```

or whatever the equivelent is

or even just use naive regex

```
print re.findall("lastPrice\W*([0-9,])",my_page_text)
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. I'm now getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Here is my entire code